# React function not returning <div> element

Tags: reactjs

In the following code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { val: '' };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ val: e.target.value });
    }

    OddEven(num) {
        const number = parseInt(num);
        let description;

        if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                description = <strong>even</strong>;
            } else {
                description = <i>odd</i>;
            }

            alert(number);

            return (
                <h1>
                    Test
                </h1>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button onClick={() =>this.OddEven(this.state.val) }>
                    Odd Even
                </button>
            </div>
        );
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

the `OddEven()` is not returning the `div`. Can't figure out why for the last 2 hours. I'm in the learning phase. So don't get offended if it's something silly.

Comment: What do you mean by not returning the 'div' ??

Comment: @scunliffe You don't need to define it as a function inside a react class

Comment: Does your alert() get called? e.g. if you don't change the value from the default `""` (empty string),... this line will return false: `Number.isInteger("")`

Comment: For what are you using 'description', you are setting it up but never use it, also 'OddEven' returns null or <h1> element, there is no div in this function.

Comment: OOOOPs sorry guys, my MISTAKE. Originally the 'OddEven' was written as a function outside the class like 'function OddEven()' and the function has to be called from button 'onclick()' along with the state. 'description' has to be returned. Really SORRY.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return your description here is how to do it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { 
   val: '',
   description: null,
    };

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ val: e.target.value });
}

OddEven(num) {
    const number = parseInt(num);
    let {description} = this.state;
    if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            description = <strong>even</strong>;
        } else {
            description = <i>odd</i>;
        }

        this.setState({description: description});
    } else {
        this.setState({description: null});
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <button onClick={() =>this.OddEven(this.state.val) }>
            Odd Even Check?
            </button>
            {this.state.description}
        </div>
        );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: OOOOPs sorry guys, my MISTAKE. Originally the 'OddEven' was written as a function outside the class like 'function OddEven()' and the function has to be called from button 'onclick()' along with the state. 'description' has to be returned. Really SORRY.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not rendering what your function returns anywhere, what you would rather want to do is this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { val: "", oddeven: "" }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ val: e.target.value })
  }

  OddEven = () => {
    const number = parseInt(this.state.val) //Use the state directly
    let description
    if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
      if (number % 2 == 0) {
        description = <strong>even</strong>
      } else {
        description = <i>odd</i>
      }
      alert(number)
      this.setState({ oddEven: "Hello" })
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.OddEven}>Odd Even</button> {/* you do not need to passs the state here, you can directly access it in your function */}
        {this.state.oddEven && <h1>{this.state.oddEven}</h1>}  {/* Here we check if oddEven exists and then we display whatever we set in the OddEven function}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here we set the state to what you want to render and then use that inside our render function.

Comment: OOOOPs sorry guys, my MISTAKE. Originally the 'OddEven' was written as a function outside the class like 'function OddEven()' and the function has to be called from button 'onclick()' along with the state. 'description' has to be returned. Really SORRY.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = { val: '' };

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ val: e.target.value });
}

OddEven(num) {
    const number = parseInt(num);
    if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return <strong>even</strong>;
        } else {
            return <i>odd</i>;
        }

    } else {
        return <a>Please Enter A Number</a>;
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} />
            {OddEven(this.state.val)}
        </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: OOOOPs sorry guys, my MISTAKE. Originally the 'OddEven' was written as a function outside the class like 'function OddEven()' and the function has to be called from button 'onclick()' along with the state. 'description' has to be returned. Really SORRY.